# Simple XSLT template failing in some cases

Tags: xslt

Part of some XSLT I am working on is this very simple template to show up an unresolved reference type of error.

```
<!-- a basic check when matching on copying index elements - are they referring to a defined item element -->
    <xsl:template match="index" mode="expand">
      <xsl:variable name="index_name_xml"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></xsl:variable>
      <xsl:if test="not(//item[@name=$index_name_xml])">
        <xsl:message terminate="yes"><xsl:value-of select="concat('FAIL : cannot find &quot;',$index_name_xml,'&quot; in items')"/></xsl:message>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

When this element

```
<index name="User X Ordinate"/>
```

is matched in input doc the above template is called, the templates xpath SHOULD find this node (in input doc)

```
<item  name="User X Ordinate"              address="UserXOrd_s"                usage="realtime"      type="uint16_t"        unit="unit_ordinate_q8"  />
```

but it doesn't and I get my fail message

```
FAIL : cannot find "User X Ordinate" in dbitems Error at char 7 in xsl:value-of/@select on line 253 column 130 of db_expander.xsl: 
XTMM9000: Processing terminated by xsl:message at line 253 in db_expander.xsl
```

and I am scratching my head as there are dozens of cases in my transformation where the template does what I want, and TWO cases when it doesn't (a clue I cant figure out yet). I cant see any spelling errors and the two slashes in the xpath should mean ALL 'item' elements at any level in the document are checked. I cant see how is doesn't work.

**EDIT** :: Apologies for this amateurish post.  I kind of got lost trying to recreate a simple version of the problem where I could post the whole source.   My partial understanding is that the problem may be related to how the XSL is passing the node /context into the template -- its slightly out of my depth at the moment but -- result tree fragment / context in the source XML?

However, if I add a 'root' variable into the template (shown below) the template does what I want -- the problems are gone -- so the problem seems to be relating to the context being passed.  I tried but failed to make a small stand alone example that fails to post here -- my tests kept working...so I am obviously still not grasping a finer point(s) yet.

```
  <xsl:variable name="root" select="/"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="index" mode="expand">
    <xsl:variable name="index_name" >  <xsl:value-of select="@name"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$root//dbgroup//item[@name=$index_name]">
        <!--xsl:message terminate="no">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('item found for : ',$index_name, ' (parent is ',parent::node()/@name,')')"/>
        </xsl:message-->
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:message terminate="no">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('item NOT found for : ',$index_name, ' (parent is ',parent::node()/@name,')')"/>
        </xsl:message>
      </xsl:otherwise>    
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

I need to do some more reading as I dont know a good way to debug this other than xsl:messages....

Comment: Without providing a way to reproduce the problem, the most you will get are guesses.

Comment: Are there namespaces involved?

Comment: No namespaces are involved.

Answer (score 0):

If a template is supplied with an RTF (result tree fragment) then unfortunately '//*' doesn't refer to ANY element in the hierarchy of the source document anymore, but rather ANY element in the RTF hierarchy which does not contain all the elements (in my case / most cases) of the source document.

Hence why I needed to use the $root variable inside the template in my 'EDIT' above in order to get access to elements not in the RTF.

The trick is knowing that you will end up with an RTF when you apply templates within a variable declaration in order to populate it. And so when this is passed to a template, you will need another way to get back to the context of your source document.